# how to make User Input of 10 digit Mobile number into 3 - 3 - 4 pattern

Tags: java, android

How to make make user input of 10 digit mobile number into 3-3-4 format?
example of 9848098480 into (984)-809-8480 in android??

Comment: Valid phone number length is constant, you can substring the phone number string and display those parts in required format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html), just call:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

---

**Addition**
To be clear, PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher's [backbone](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java#PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.afterTextChanged%28android.text.Editable%29) is the PhoneNumberUtils class. The difference is the TextWatcher maintains the EditText while you must call `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber()` every time you change its contents.

***OR***

You can use this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone" />
```

Then try this code:

```
final EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(com.and.R.id.editText1);

    text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            boolean flag = true;
            String eachBlock[] = text.getText().toString().split("-");
            for (int i = 0; i < eachBlock.length; i++) {
                if (eachBlock[i].length() > 4) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {

                text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                            keyDel = 1;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                if (keyDel == 0) {

                    if (((text.getText().length() + 1) % 5) == 0) {

                        if (text.getText().toString().split("-").length <= 3) {
                            text.setText(text.getText() + "-");
                            text.setSelection(text.getText().length());
                        }
                    }
                    a = text.getText().toString();
                } else {
                    a = text.getText().toString();
                    keyDel = 0;
                }

            } else {
                text.setText(a);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use Himanshu Agarwal's method or just do:

```
String number = "1234567899";
System.out.println("(" + number.substring(0, 3) + ")-"
        + number.substring(3, 6) + "-" + number.substring(6));
```

ouput:

> (123)-456-7899